# changing string (numerical) to float in php

Tags: php

Ive got data coming in from an xml feed the attribute that im using from this feed is written `Decimal="1.14"` and `Decimal="2.00"` what i want to do is use these attributes in a function and to be able to compare them.

like this

```
if($provider1 > $provider2){
        return $provider1;
    }
    else {
        return $provider2;
    }
```

How can i convert these numbers into a float to be used in the function

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

This should help you achieve what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function: `floatval`

The documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

You can then do something like this:

```
if (floatval($provider1) > floatval($provider2)) {
    return $provider1;
} else {
    return $provider2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `floatval($value)` or `(float) $value`. See type-casting here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use floatval() to convert string to float. To get the strings use any xml library.